# Can we get some information about search term statistics

Tags: discussion, tags, search, statistics

Can we get some information about search term statistics in Stack Overflow.

Users may input terms (tags or phrase) that are supposed to be included in the intended content.

In other words, I want to know what kind of terms do users usually use for search?

e.g. c#, c++, java, error, memory exception  and so on

What I want to extract out of the information is the feature of query terms.

When users try to search for articles in Stack Overflow,
- they are likely to use terms describing the development environment such as language name, framework name...
- or to use terms describing problematic situation like error-handling and memoryleaks...

More concretely I want to get the portion of terms given each perspective.

Comment: Is this for a new site that will have people posting questions and answers on programming questions and vote on the quality/correctness of such?

Comment: @random: I think the OP just wants search stats from Stack Overflow.

Comment: Only one hit for 'temrs' and 'environmet'.  These stats are not available.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking for _search engine_ queries that lead people here, or queries run on the internal search? I don't see anything 'bad' with providing either, but there may be factors I'm not considering.

Comment: @Tim Post: Yes, both can be helpful. But, I don't really concern the former, rather focus on latter. That's why I ask it here. Is anybody who know about someon in charge of this stuff, meaning that where can I ask in order to get exact information?